# Visibility="Collapsed" Doesn't work is there a need to something extra or not

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to change the position of my `TextBox` when the upper textbox is to be invisbile how can i achieve it ? I m using wpf c#.

I m using `Visibility="Collapsed"` 
but it take the space .

Comment: you mean the textbox to be move top , bottom etc... like that

Comment: Please explain your scenario better so that we will not have to take guesses.

Comment: Are you positive you are using "Collapsed" and not "Hidden"?  

Visibility.Hidden will make the textbox invisible, but maintain its position (reserve its space), while Visibility.Collapsed will make it invisible and relinquish the space.

If you are, in fact, using Collapsed, then you must have some other layout issue - as @Veer says, please explain (and/or post your example)

Comment: It really depends on the the layout of the control hosting the TextBoxes.
Which Panel are you using to layout the TextBox controls?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows what I mean in my last comment, based on clues from your question and comment.  It shows how Visible, Hidden, and Collapsed work in a StackPanel, in a grid with fixed row heights, and in a grid with auto row heights.

This is pretty basic stuff, but hopefully it will help you, and any future Google searches.

```
<Window x:Class="CollapsedExample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Collapsed Example" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="rectBase" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="rectCollapsing" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource rectBase}"
               TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioVisible, 
                                               Path=IsChecked}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioHidden, 
                                               Path=IsChecked}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioCollapsed, 
                                               Path=IsChecked}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="labelStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="gridLayout" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <!-- Stack Panel -->
        <Label Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.Row="0"
               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
               Content="Stack Panel" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackExample"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1">
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectCollapsing}"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Fill="Green" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Grid with Fixed Sizes -->
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectShading" 
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Fill="LightGray" />

        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
               Grid.Row="0"
               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
               Content="Grid (Fixed Row Size)" />
        <Grid x:Name="gridFixedRowsExample"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectCollapsing}"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Fill="Green" />
        </Grid>


        <!-- Grid with Auto Sizes -->
        <Label Grid.Column="2" 
               Grid.Row="0"
               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
               Content="Grid (Auto Row Size)" />
        <Grid x:Name="gridAutoRowsExample"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectCollapsing}"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectBase}"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Fill="Green" />
        </Grid>


        <!-- Options -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackOptions"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <RadioButton x:Name="radioVisibile"
                         IsChecked="True"
                         Margin="5"
                         Content="Red Rectangle is Visible" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="radioHidden"
                         Margin="5"
                         Content="Red Rectangle is Hidden" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="radioCollapsed"
                         Margin="5"
                         Content="Red Rectangle is Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the `Visibility="Collapsed"` on the `TextBox`....

[MSDN Visibility Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980164(v=VS.95).aspx)

Comment: WPF Visibility enumerations has three values : Visible, Hidden and Collapsed. I believe the link you posted is not correct.

Comment: The link above is for Silverlight, which is slightly different.  The link that I believe you want is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx

Comment: Its Work Only With in A Stackpanel Not iN a grid

Comment: It depends on how you define your grid.  If you define your RowDefinitions to have a set height (either an actual number, or to "*"), then the row will have that height, regardless of the contents.  If you set the height to Auto, it will size it to the contents.

Comment: I confirm, the link I posted is for Silverlight... I quickly googled it just to provide a link to the user... my intention was to point him towards the right direction...

As @Wonko said, I guess there are other layout issues... Collapsed should ...collapse the item and "remove" the space that it occupies.  If this is not happening, it means you set up the size to some fixed value somehow... 

Some code to look at would be great. We might provide a better hand...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to set a GUI component's Visibility value to a String value.  What you have to do is set it to the predefined constant in System.Windows.Visibility.

Let's say you're working with a text box called myTextBox in the code for example.  What you have to do is set:

```
myTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

If you try to set it to the String "Collapsed" it won't know what to do with the value.